# How to create a custom document in collection - Firestore with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I sign in my user through google, after successfully login. I wants to create document for each user inside **user_details** collection and the document name should be **google id**. But its auto generating document name.

Is there any way to create custom document in Firestore?

Thanks in Advance

```
// Store data in Firestore
storeData(User user) async {
  DocumentReference documentRef =
  Firestore.instance.collection("user_details").document(user.id);

  Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
    await transaction.set(documentRef, user.toJson());
    print("instance created");
    _login.add(Result(Status.SUCCESS, "Login successful.", user));
  });
}
```

Comment: Try this `await documentRef.setData(user.toJson());`

Comment: @HarjotSingh Yes its working

Comment: Then I am adding as an answer please accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `await documentRef.setData(user.toJson());`